# How to get the UserID in a form to add it a table?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to get the UserID from my Table "users" and add it in a form inside an Activity where I add new Offers to my table "products". I already know how to get the UserID from my Table, but i dont know how to insert it in the form.

How to get the UserID

```
public int getuserid(String username) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from user where username=?", new String[]{username});
    if (cursor.getCount()>0)
        return cursor.getInt(0);
    else
        return 0;

}
}
```

EDIT

My AddOffers Acticity,

```
   @Override


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addofferactivity);
    myTraderDbHelper = new MyTraderDbHelper(this);

    add_art = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_art);
    add_namep = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_namep);
    add_menge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_menge);
    add_standort = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_standort);
    add_gueltigbis = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_gueltigbis);
    add_userzuordnung = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_userzuordnung);
    add_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_button);
    AddOffer();

}



public void AddOffer(){
    RegDBHelper regDBhelper = new RegDBHelper(this);
    regDBhelper.getuserid();
    add_button.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    if (add_namep.getText().toString()!=null){
                        String username = add_namep.getText().toString();
                        boolean isInsirted = myTraderDbHelper.addOffer(add_art.getText().toString(),
                                add_namep.getText().toString(),
                                add_menge.getText().toString(),
                                add_standort.getText().toString(),
                                add_gueltigbis.getText().toString(),
                                getuserid(username)
                        add_userzuordnung.setText(""+getuserid(username));
                    }
                    if (isInserted =true)
                        Toast.makeText(AddOffersActivity.this,"Hinzugefügt",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(AddOffersActivity.this,"Nicht hinzugefügt",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    );
}
```

There is an Error in the third line in the brackets, in the 15th and 16th line

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
public void AddOffer(String art, String namep, String menge, String standort, String gueltigbis, String userzuordnung) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, art);
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME_NAMEP, namep);
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME_MENGE, menge);
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME_STANDORT, standort);
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME_GUELTIGBIS, gueltigbis);
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME_USERZOUDNUNG, userzuordnung);

    long newRowId = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values)
}
```

or if you want to update the row of the table with userId

```
 public Int updateOffer(Int userId, String art, String namep, String menge, String standort, String gueltigbis, String userzuordnungl)
    {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, art);
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME_NAMEP, namep);
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME_MENGE, menge);
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME_STANDORT, standort);
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME_GUELTIGBIS, gueltigbis);
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME_USERZOUDNUNG, userzuordnung);
        return db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "UserId=?" + userId,null)
    }
```

Comment: All the adds except the "userzuordnung" are working. My Problem is I dont know how to insert the UserID from the userDB in "userzuordnung" to save it in the Database Products

Comment: I have a form where the User can fill in e.g. title, name...   But now I want to fill in the Column "userzuordnung" automatically with the UserID when the User is logged in

Comment: I think it would not be good to have many databases for an application, what you should have is multiple tables.

Choose a primary key and foreign keys which will be present in most tables sp that you can pick records out of tables uniquely.

Comment: The application only has two databases, for the records I use primary keys

Answer (score 0):

You could put

```
if (add_namep.getText().toString()!=null){
String username = add_namep.getText().toString();
boolean isInsirted = myTraderDbHelper.addOffer(add_art.getText().toString(),
                            add_namep.getText().toString(),
                            add_menge.getText().toString(),
                            add_standort.getText().toString(),
                            add_gueltigbis.getText().toString(),
                            getuserid(username);
add_userzuordnung.setText(""+getuserid(username))
}
```

Or am I getting anything wrong?

Comment: I think thats what im looking for, I put your code in the AddOffer method. And the getuserid above the AddOffer method. But now I have a Problem with 'SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();' The method getReadableDatabase is resolved

Comment: The getuserid method cannot be in your activity. It must be in a class that extends SqliteDbHelper. Than in your activity you call an instance of this class like that: MyDbHelper myDbHelper = MyDbHelper.getInstance() an than you call myDbHelper.getuserid(username). But if your first issue is solved, please mark my answer as accepted answer. Thank you!